# how to hide inactive data in active admin dashboard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am trying to hide data which have an active/inactive boolean tag. On the dashboard of my active admin app I only want the active driver data to be shown.

For each panel I have the following code:

```
column do
      span
      #if Driver.where(status: "false", active: true).unscope(where: :status) == Driver.where(active: false)
      if Driver.where( 'v_ins_exp < ?', Time.now).present?

        panel "Vehicle Insurance expired" do
            table_for Driver.where('v_ins_exp < ?', Time.now).reverse_order do |t|
              t.column "REMNET ID", :remnet
              t.column "First Name", :f_name
              t.column "Last Name", :l_name
              t.column "Vehicle Make", :v_make
              t.column "Vehicle Reg",:v_reg
              t.column("Insurance Date") { |driver| driver.v_ins_exp? ? l(driver.v_ins_exp, :format => :long) : '-' }
            end
          #end
        end
      end 
    end
```

I have # the line where i used the IF statment, currently it removed all data from the panel without checking the status of the driver.

I have also tried using scope and default_scope but it throws back 'undefined method' error.

Im not sure if its my approach thats wrong or the code thats wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, this worked for me:

```
if Driver.where( 'v_ins_exp < ?', Time.now).present? 
        panel "Vehicle Insurance expired" do
            table_for Driver.where('v_ins_exp < ?', Time.now).reverse_order.where(:status => true) do |t|
              t.column "REMNET ID", :remnet
              t.column "First Name", :f_name
              t.column "Last Name", :l_name
              t.column "Vehicle Make", :v_make
              t.column "Vehicle Reg",:v_reg
              t.column("Insurance Date") { |driver| driver.v_ins_exp? ? l(driver.v_ins_exp, :format => :long) : '-' }
            end
        end
      end 
    end
```

rather than passing an IF statement i added the condition on the table_for line:

```
table_for Driver.where('v_ins_exp < ?', Time.now).reverse_order.where(:status => true) do |t|
```

Looks like a silly thing to have been stuck on, but learning as I go along! :)